# How to pass parameters in JSF 2.0 without using <f:param>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

in JSF 2.0 it's now possible to pass parameters to a managed bean simply by following this syntax:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{classMB.delete(1)}" />
```

here is the MB:

```
String delete(int id) {
      EJBinstance.delete(id);
      return "success";
}
```

What i need is how to change the `#{classMB.delete(1)}` by something link: `#classMB.delete(#{user.id})` of course we'll suppose that we're working inside a datatable

```
<h:dataTable value="#{clientMB.listClients}" var="user" class = "table1">
```

where we're getting user informations...

Comment: Uhmmmm by doing `#{classMB.delete(user.id)}` ? Like in all EL where you pass parameters

Comment: I was not thinking... that was stupid ! thanks... any ideas tho if we can pass multiple params ? using this same approach of course..